# How to save a 3D data matrix as pointcloud in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, point-clouds

I have a 3D data matrix which contains information about a scene (which voxels are free / occupied and belong to which class).

So far to plot the data I have to plot 2D slices using `imagesc`.

I'd like to plot the data as a pointcloud using Matlabs `pcshow` which should only display occupied voxels and the display the rest as empty space.

How can I convert my 3D matrix into a pointcloud object?

Comment: how are "free" voxels defined? Are they `NaN` or `0`?

Comment: I could convert them to any uint32 bit value. So far free voxels are encoded as `255`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some NxMxK matrix `A` where `A == 255` indicates free voxels:

```
% make coordinate grid the size of A
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2),1:size(A,3));
% move to xyz format
xyz=[X(:) Y(:) Z(:)];
% show points which are not free and where group values are used as color (scaled by to current colormap)
pcshow(xyz(A~=255,:),A(A~=255))
```